# how to set authorization scope using Google login button

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am integrating with Google Drive.  I have followed the Google recommended path of putting the login button like this:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSuccessFunc" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

This class of g-signin2 enable certain callbacks, but I can't find the documentation anywhere.  Searches are pointless since there a million examples of code using this.  Can someone point out the documentation?

My problem is that I need to enable google drive access.  That is done in gapi.init however this login button is doing the init itself, and if I try to do it, it complains that init has already been called.  OK, but I need to specify the authentication scope to include google drive.

When I execute the program, pressing on the button prompts to allow profile access, but not drive.

Later, I call gapi.auth.authorize which simply fails without prompting the user.  I have seen other uses of the g-signin2 class with other parameter attributes, and I suspect there is an attribute for this, but I am at a loss to find the documentation.  Unfortunately the Google tutorials do not reference the documentation about the fields and their meanings.

Any idea how to tell the login button the authorization scopes to present to the user?

```
$scope.callAuthAuthorize = function() {
    var authparam = {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'immediate': true
    };
    console.log("Now Requesting: ", authparam);
    gapi.auth.authorize(authparam, $scope.handleAuthResult);
}
```

Comment: would [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [JavaScript Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) for Google Drive API.
That is what I used to create an app that reads files from Google Drive.

Follow the steps in "Step 1: Turn on the Drive API" to enable credentials in your Google Cloud account.

First call `authorize` with `immediate: true`, then switch to `immediate: false` on error:

```
gapi.auth.authorize(authparam, (auth_result)=> {
    if (auth_result && !auth_result.error)
        $scope.handleAuthResult(auth_result)
    else {
        authparam.immediate = false;
        gapi.auth.authorize(authparam, (auth_result)=> {
            if (auth_result && !auth_result.error)
                $scope.handleAuthResult(auth_result)
            else
                console.error(auth_result)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah I have done that.  The problem is that the client API is initialized automagically and there is no documentation on it.  I have all the code in that sample coded the same way, but the call to `gapi.auth.authorize` simply fails. (and reports a very good error message by the way).  So I know exactly what it wrong. But I can't find out how to configure the login button to ASK for the right permissions.

Comment: You should be passing `{scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'}` in your `gapi.auth.authorize` call, along with your `client_id`. I am calling it twice, the first time with `immediate: true` and then on failure it attempts with `immediate: false`.

Comment: I have included the code for authorize in top post.  The second call is exactly the same except for the immediate variable?

Comment: Yes, just update the `immediate` value. Have updated my answer with your code.

Comment: That worked, so thanks.  I did not find that in the reference doc you linked.  Is that the best reference for this issue?

Comment: That code in the link follows the same process, but at different times. It does the first `authorize` call on library load (see `script[src]` tag) and the second (`immediate: false`) call when the user clicks the button.